# How to get the all http requests headers from the proxy server using c language

Tags: c, http, http-headers

I want to get the all http requests which are going through proxy. And i need to show them in an output file

Actually my proxy server is storing all the requests in STDIN. So now i should get the data/header requests from that STDIN. Is that possible to get? if possible please let me know how to proceed

Comment: WHat have you tried? Clearly it's possible in a theoretical sense, but you don't give enough details for us to tell where you are stuck.

Comment: @paul thanks for your reply. Ok i will explain you clearly.

Comment: Am using one proxy server in between client and server. So whenever i surf through browsers all the requests will goes through proxy. Proxy will send those requests via STDIN. SO all requests will be present in STDIN. Now i need to get the requests headers from that STDIN

Comment: Good.  PLease read the help pages about asking a good question. This isn' (yet) a good question and will get closed quickly unless you improve it.

Comment: You;ve just repeated your question without adding anything useful. So, the info is on STDIN. What is your approach? What have you tried? What has worked and what has not? SO is not a place for people to write your code for you

Comment: ***[How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help)*** is included on this page

Comment: Seems like a simple command-line redirect of STDOUT (not STDIN) should do the trick...no programming necessary!